# Add item into List from View Loaded Dynamically and pass it to Controller in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, razorengine

I am working on Mobile Store Management System's Order page. I want to allow users to select a company through a select list, and then select multiple models of that company from another select list which is loaded dynamically through AJAX.

The code for the cascading models is working, but I am unable to send the selected models to the server because it is adding them in the DOM through JavaScript.

The following is the code for the cascading selection:

```html
<div class="form-group row">
    <label  class="control-label col-6">Company Name</label>
    <div class="col-12">
        <select id="CompanyId"  class="custom-select mr-sm-2"
                asp-items="@(new SelectList( 
                @ViewBag.Companies,"Phoneid","Com_name"))">
            <option value="">Please Select</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <span class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
    <label  class="control-label col-6"></label>
    <div class="col-12">
        <select id="modelId" multiple class="custom-select mr-sm-2"
                asp-items="@(new SelectList(string.Empty,"modelId","model_name","--Select--"))">
            <option value="">Please Select</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <span class="text-danger"></span>
</div> 
<div>
     <input type="button" id="saveBtn" value="Save" />
</div>
```

**Cascading Code:**

```js
$("#CompanyId").change(async function() 
{
  await $.getJSON("/Order/GetAllModels",{ PhoneId: $("#CompanyId").val()}, 
  function(data) 
  {
    $("#modelId").empty();
    $.each(data, function (index, row) {
        $("#modelId").append("<option value='" + row.modelId + "'>" + 
          row.model_name + '</option>')
    });
  });
}
```

Once the <kbd>Save</kbd> button is clicked, I am displaying the product for the currently selected models using a partial view:

```js
$('#saveBtn').click(function () {   
  $.ajax({
    url: '/Order/GetProduct?Phoneid=' + $("#CompanyId").val() + "&modelId=" + $('#modelId').val(),
    type: 'Post',
    success: function (data) {
      $('#products').append(data);
    },
  })
})
```

#### Problem 1

When the user selects the first company and their two models, and then clicks the <kbd>Save</kbd> button, the partial view loads with indexes `i=0,i=1`. Then, the user selects another company and selects their models. Again, the partial view renders with same indexes. How can I make the indexes unique? This partial view is rendered when the user clicks the <kbd>Save</kbd> button, which renders only the current company's selected models.

```html
@model List<Mobile_Store_MS.ViewModel.Orders.Products>
<table class="table">
    <tbody>
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
        {
            <tr class="card d-flex">
                <td>
                    <input asp-for="@Model[i].isSelected" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input hidden asp-for="@Model[i].Phoneid" />  <input hidden asp-for="@Model[i].modelId" />
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model[i].com_Name)   @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model[i].model_name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input asp-for="@Model[i].Quantity" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input class="disabled" readonly asp-for="@Model[i].price" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

#### Problem 2

How can I send all of the items rendered through the partial view to the server? I just want to send these selected products along with the quantity and price for each model to the server. This means binding these items in the product list of the `OrderViewModel`.

You can find my `OrderViewModel` and `Products` model in the following diagram:

[image]

Can you tell me how to bind Razor items into a list to post to the controller? I would be very grateful if you give me some suggestions.

#### Related

- [Link of my Previous Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61962733/add-item-to-c-sharp-list-on-selectchange-loaded-through-cascading)
- [Sample of my order page](https://github.com/sami-lab/sample)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Instead of relying on the `asp-for` tag helper, you can set your own `name` attribute. This gives you the flexibility to start the index at whatever number you want. Ideally, you will pass the number of existing products to `GetProduct()` and start indexing off of that. In addition, you also need to prefix your `name` attribute with `Products`, thus ensuring those form elements are properly bound to your `OrderViewModel.Products` collection on post back.

```html
<input name="Products[@(startIndex+i)].Quantity" value="@Model[i].Quantity" />
```

You can then filter the `OrderViewModel.Products` collection on the server-side using LINQ to limit the results to selected products:

```cs
var selectedProducts = c.Products.Where(p => p.IsSelected);
```

For a more in-depth explanation of how this approach works, as well as some of the variations in the implementation, read my full answer below.

---

## Detailed Answer

There's a lot going on here, so this is going to be a lengthy answer. I'm going to start by providing some critical background on how ASP.NET Core MVC connects the dots between your view model, your view, and your binding model, as that will better understand how to adapt this behavior to your needs. Then I'm going to provide a strategy for solving each of your problems.

> *Note:* I'm not going to write all of the code, as that would result in me reinventing a lot of code you've already written—and would make for an even longer answer. Instead, I'm going to provide a checklist of steps needed to apply the solution to your existing code.

### Background

It's important to note that while ASP.NET Core MVC attempts to standardize and simplify the workflow from view model to view to binding model through conventions (such as the `asp-for` tag helper) these are each independent of one another.

So when you call `asp-for` on a collection using e.g.,

```html
<input asp-for="@Model[i].Quantity" />
```

It then outputs the something like the following HTML:

```html
<input id="0__Quantity" name="[0].Quantity" value="1" />
```

And then, when you submit that, the server looks at your form data, and uses [a set of conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1) to map that data back to your binding model. So this might map to:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> ProductsAsync(List<Product> products) { … }
```

When you call `asp-for` on a collection, it will always start the index at `0`. And when it bind the form data to a binding model, it will always start at `[0]` and count up.

But there's no reason you *need* to use `asp-for` if you need to change this behavior. You can instead set the `id` and/or `name` attributes yourself if you need flexibility over how they are generated.

> *Note:* When you do this, you'll want to make sure you're still sticking to one of [the conventions that ASP.NET Core MVC is already familiar with](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1) to ensure data binding occurs. Though, if you *really* want to, you can instead [create your own binding conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

### Problem 1: Setting the index

Given the above background, if you want to customize the starting index returned from your call to `GetProducts()` for your second model, you‘ll want to do something like the following:

1. Before calling `GetProduct()`, determine how many products you already have by e.g. counting the number of elements with the `card` class assigned (i.e., `$(".card").length`).

   > *Note:* If the `card` class is not exclusively used for products, you can instead assign a unique class like `product` to each `tr` element in your `_DisplayOrder` view and count that.
2. Include this count in your call to `GetProduct()` as e.g., a `&startingIndex=` parameter:

```js
$('#saveBtn').click(function () {   
  $.ajax({
    url: '/Order/GetProduct?Phoneid=' + $("#CompanyId").val() + "&modelId=" + $('#modelId').val() + "&startingIndex=" + $("#card").length,
    type: 'Post',
    success: function (data) {
      $('#products').append(data);
    },
  })
})
```

```cs
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult GetProduct(int Phoneid, string[] modelId, int startingIndex = 0) { … }
```

3. Relay this `startingIndex` to your "partial" view via a view model; e.g.,

```cs
public class ProductListViewModel {
  public int StartingIndex { get; set; }
  public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

4. Use that value to offset the index written to the output:

```html
<input id="@(Model.StartingIndex+i)__Quantity" name="[@(Model.StartingIndex+i)].Quantity" value="@Model.Products[i].Quantity" />
```

That's not as tidy as `asp-for` since you're needing to wire up a lot of similar information, but it offers you the flexibility to ensure that your `name` values are unique on the page, no matter how many times you call `GetProduct()`.

#### Notes

- If you don't want to create a new view model, you *could* relay the `startingIndex` via your `ViewData` dictionary instead. I prefer having a view model that includes all of the data I need, though.
- When using the `asp-for` tag helper, it automatically generates the `id` attribute, but if you're not ever referencing it via e.g. JavaScript you can omit it.
- Browsers will only submit values to the server for form elements that have a `name` attribute. So if you have input elements that are needed on the client-side but *aren't* needed in the binding model, for some reason, you can omit the `name` attribute.
- There are other conventions besides `{Index}__{Property}` that you can follow. But unless you *really* want to get into the weeds of model binding, you're best off sticking to one of the [existing collection conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1#collections).

#### Be careful of your indexing!

In the [Model Binding conventions for collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1#collections), you'll notice a warning:

> Data formats that use subscript numbers (... [0] ... [1] ...) must ensure that they are numbered sequentially starting at zero. If there are any gaps in subscript numbering, all items after the gap are ignored. For example, if the subscripts are 0 and 2 instead of 0 and 1, the second item is ignored.

As such, when assigning these, you need to make sure that they're sequential without any gaps. If you're using the count (`.length`) of existing e.g. `$(".card")` or `$(".product")` elements on your page to seed the `startingIndex` value, however, then that shouldn't be a problem.

### Problem 2: Sending these values to the server

As mentioned above, any form element with a `name` attribute will have its data submitted to the server. So it doesn't really matter if you're using `asp-for`, writing out your form manually using HTML, or constructing it dynamically using JavaScript. If there's a form element with a `name` attribute, and it's within the `form` being submitted, it will get included in the payload.

#### Debugging your form data

You're likely already familiar with this, but if not: If you use your browser's developer console, you'll be able to see this information as part of the page metadata when you submit your form. For instance, in Google Chrome:

- Go to *Developer Tools* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>)
- Go to the *Network* tab
- Submit your form
- Click on the name of your page (normally the first entry)
- Go to the <kbd>Headers</kbd> tab
- Scroll down to the *Form Data* section (or *Query String Parameters* for a `GET` request)

You should see something like:

- **[0].isSelected** true
- **[0].Phoneid** 4
- **[0].modelId** 10
- **[0].Quantity** 5
- **[0].price** 10.50
- **[1].isSelected** true
- **[…]…**

If you're seeing these in Chrome, but not seeing these data reflected in your ASP.NET Core MVC controller action, then there's a disconnect between the naming conventions of these fields and your binding model—and, thus, ASP.NET Core MVC doesn't know how to map the two.

#### Binding Problems

There are two likely issues here, both of which might be interfering with your data binding.

**Duplicate Indexes**

Since you are currently submitting duplicate indexes, that *could* be causing collisions with the data. E.g., if there are two values for `[0].Quantity`, then it will retrieve those as an array—and may fail to bind either value to e.g. the `int Quantity` property on your `Products` binding model. I haven't tested this, though, so I'm not entirely sure how ASP.NET Core MVC deals with this situation.

**Collection Name**

When you bind to a `List<Products>` with the `asp-for` tag helper, I *believe* it will use the `[i].Property` naming convention. That's a problem because your `OrderViewModel` is not a collection. Instead, these needs to be associated with the `Products` property on your binding model. That can be done by prefixing the `name` with `Products`. This will be done automatically if you use `asp-for` to bind to a `Products` property on your view model—as proposed on the `ProductListViewModel` above. But since you need to dynamically generate the `name`'s based on the `IndexOffset` anyway, you can just hard-code these as part of your template:

```html
<input id="Products_@(Model.StartingIndex+i)__Quantity" name="Products[@(Model.StartingIndex+i)].Quantity" value="@Model.Products[i].Quantity" />
```

#### Selected Products

There's still a problem, though! This is going to include *all* of your products—even if they weren't otherwise selected by the user. There are a number of strategies for dealing with this, from dynamically filtering them on the client, to creating a custom model binder that first validates the `Products_[i]__isSelected` attribute. The easiest, though, is to simply allow all of them to be bound to your binding model, and then filter them prior to any processing using e.g. LINQ:

```cs
var selectedProducts = c.Products.Where(p => p.IsSelected).ToList();
…
repo.SetProducts(selectedProducts);
```

Comment: I've updated my answer after going through your GitHub repo. Previously, I had made some assumptions and proposed some scaffolding based on code that wasn't present in your question—such as the `OrderController` class, the `Create()` action, and the `OrderViewModel` binding model. After evaluating these on GitHub, I've removed my proposed action and binding model, and instead provided an assessment of why you're not likely seeing the data properly bound.

Comment: Thank You So Much Finally i have solved this issue.

Comment: I’m glad I could help! It’s an interesting problem and not one I’ve run into before.

Comment: I am sorry I am disturbing you again but there is problem I just notice. Actually I make some changes in code and removed Isselected  property from Products model now I render close button(x) in every Product I display through partial View and on clicking of this button Complete div of that product Will Remove. This Is same solution I also provided in my github code. Normally every website allow user to Remove product by Clicking on Any close button and not just through select so Their is problem coming with this approach

Comment: I am Explaining problem with Example. Suppose user selects 2 Models So Current length is 2 and Input is Generated with Indexes of 0 and 1 now suppose user remove product with 0 Index now current length Changes to 1 and only one input with Index 1 is left on my order page. Now when User again Add any other product, input is generated with Index of 1 again because total_model_length(index) +i =1+0= 1 but input with Index 1 Is Already present on My order page as well As their is Missing Index 0 in my list.

Comment: @MuhammadSami: Ah, yes! I see what you mean. That thought was actually nagging at me when I wrote this, but I had put it aside since it didn't address your immediate questions. I should have spent more time thinking through the implications of that. Let me organize my thoughts on that, and [we can discuss this further in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215614/discussion-between-jeremy-caney-and-muhammad-sami).

Answer (score 1):

For the 1st question, you can try different things. When you do the ajax call, you get a list of models. For each of these models, add the selected company ID as a property. So you don't have to worry about the index being something unique.

As for the 2nd question, should be a relatively easy thing to do. However, more information is needed.
1. When the save button is hit, are you doing a full postback? or it is also an AJAX call?
2. Why do you not want to opt for a AJAX call to do the update as well? So you can based upon the response, redirect the user to a results page, etc.

If you can create a small sample in a new project, and upload to github, and post the information here. I should be able to take a look and understand better. I will definitely be able to help.

Also try reading this thread, it might help

[how to persist partial view model data during postback in asp.net mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17607665/how-to-persist-partial-view-model-data-during-postback-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: Post Edited! , https://github.com/sami-lab/Employee-Management

Comment: Using the `CompanyId` (or `modelId`) was my initial thought as well. But that’s going to cause problems since ASP.NET Core’s [model binding conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1#collections) expect collections to start at 0 and continue sequentially without any gaps.

Comment: Also, while I agree that using AJAX to submit the data is probably the most elegant approach, that shouldn’t effect the solution _too_ much since the important consideration here is ensuring that the form elements’ `name` attribute aligns with the model binding conventions. It would certainly make it easier to filter the product list by `isSelected` on the client-side, however, if that’s a requirement. (In my answer, I instead opt to filter on the server as that’s simpler.)